# Getting KeyError in request.session

Tags: python, django, session, django-forms

Here is my code for using session in Django.  Everything seems fine but getting KeyError at /addfixeddeposit/

> **views.py**

```
def anotherpage(request, account_number):
    form = FixedDepositForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    request.session['account_number'] = account_number
    return render(request, 'bankmanagement/another_page.html', context)

def addfixeddeposit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        var = request.session['account_number']
        print(var)
        form = FixedDepositForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            acc = Account.objects.get(pk = var)
            tenure = request.POST['tenure']
            rate = reuquest.POST['rate']
            new_fixed = FixedDeposit(account_number = acc, tenure = tenure, rate = rate)
            new_fixed.save()
            del request.session['account_number']
            return redirect('behome')
    return redirect('behome')
```

It's the html page in which I'm using session value. And then in addfixeddeposit in views.py

> another_page.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'addfixeddeposit' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-field">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="accountnumfield" class="label--required">Account Number</label></td>
                            <td><label id="accountnumfield">{{ request.session['account_number'] }} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="tenure" class="label--required">Tenure</label></td>
                            <td><span id='tenure'>{{ form.tenure }}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="rate" class="label--required">Rate</label></td>
                            <td><span id='rate'>{{ form.rate }}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="form-buttons">
                    <button type="submit" class="a-btn--filled">Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: which view has been called first?

Comment: Can you give the full error?

Comment: @Lemayzeur you mean function?

Comment: Maybe this typo? `rate = reuquest.POST['rate']`

Comment: @MattCremeens yes. wait a minute

Comment: @MattCremeens Yes. but it's giving me KeyError. I think it's because of session

Comment: Then please give us the full error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171026/discussion-between-abhinav-kushagra-and-matt-cremeens).

Comment: Chat is blocked on this computer. Don't you need `()` after `is_valid`?

Comment: @MattCremeens No Sir.

Comment: @MattCremeens The problem is with session

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the `()`.

Comment: Without the parens, you're testing the boolean value of the method reference, not the return value of the method. I can't think offhand of any reasonable situation under which that would return `false` - this code treats all forms as valid, and moreover doesn't actually run the cleaning code. But then it doesn't actually use the form, so that class of problem will be masked. The usual way to do something like instantiate an object based on a form plus some other information from the req is something like `new_fixed = form.save(commit=false)`, set the needed attributes, then `new_fixed.save()`.

Comment: @DeA Yes, it worked smoothly.

Comment: @MattCremeens You're right.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra I've removed my comment and put it as my answer. If it helped you, accept it, so that others may find it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're tying to send `account_number` from my templates to views, use a query string, makes it easier, like this in your templates:

`<form method="POST" action="{% url 'addfixeddeposit' %}?account_number={{account_number}}">`

And then in your `views.py` do:

`var = request.GET.get('account_number')`